# How to deploy Rails app on Max OS X, with Apache and Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, apache

Some background first so you know who you're dealing with: I'm currently teaching myself Rails. I've been through the Michael Hartl tutorial a number of times, I've created a few applications of my own and deployed them using Heroku. **Aside from that, I'm a complete beginner.**

I'm currently trying to deploy a Rails app from my own computer, using Apache. I have no previous experience with Apache, and am completely clueless when it comes to things like servers, editing configuration files, domain names, etc...

By following [these instructions](http://osxdaily.com/2012/09/02/start-apache-web-server-mac-os-x/), I have set up my machine (Macbook Pro, OS X 10.9.2) so that I can upload simple html files, and view them from another computer by entering my IP address and the file name into the browser address bar.

I then installed Passenger using homebrew.

Right now, I am trying to use [these instructions](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_deploying_a_rack_based_ruby_application_including_rails_gt_3), but there are many things I don't understand. Most of them are in this paragraph:

> Finally, we deploy it by adding the following configuration options to the Apache configuration file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.rackexample.com
    DocumentRoot /webapps/rack_example/public
    <Directory /webapps/rack_example/public>
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
        # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
        #Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

- Which configuration file should I edit? /etc/apache2/users/USERNAME.conf? Or etc/apache2/httpd.conf? Or something else? Where exactly should this new block be placed?
- What should I put as my server name? I tried it with my IP address, and it didn't seem to work. If it has something to do with my service provider, where can I find this address?
- My apps are located in /Users/user_name/rails_projects/ - so I assume I should enter "/Users/user_name/rails_projects/{webapp_name}/public" in the "Document" and "Directory" parts?

**My goal in case it is unclear:** to be able to 'launch' my apps straight from my computer, and then access them from another device using a specific address. I am quite prepared to find out that it is not as easy as deploying to Heroku.

I apologise if any or all of these questions don't make complete sense. I would like to find a simple tutorial explaining how to use Passenger with Rails, but my googling has so far been unsuccessful. Any recommendations for noob-friendly reading material (on servers, config files, mapache, domain names, etc) are much appreciated.

Thanks for reading!

**Edit: Extra information:**

I tried adding this to etc/apache2/httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /Sites/{app_name}
    <Directory /Sites/{app_name}>
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
        # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And then navigated to localhost. **Result**: webpage not available

More info:

I can't see a Sites directory in etc/apache2. But I previously    configured etc/apache2/users/user_name.conf with this:

```
<Directory "/Users/USERNAME/Sites/">
Options Indexes Multiviews
AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I then created a 'Sites' directory in Users/USERNAME as per the previously mentioned instructions. When I start Apache and navigate to my IP, any html page in that directory is accessible through my browser.

I now realise that those pages aren't actually accessible from anywhere, only from withing my network - thanks for pointing that out! Once I get my rails apps to work on Apache, I'll look into the link you sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you want to do is setup a web server.  You first begin by setting up a local webserver (installing apache, etc) this is what you're doing.  But this will only be accessible by within your LAN via localhost (ie 127.0.0.1).

To answer some of your q's:

- You edit the apache config file, which is: etc/apache2/httpd.conf
- You put your server's name, in this case its a local server, so you put localhost, ie:

  ServerName localhost
- Once you've installed apache, head over to its directory and you'll find a 'sites' directory.  That is where you put your app.  And you reference its location in the .conf file.  Since you are still a beginner, I'd advise you skip doing virtual hosts and just use the root www directory and put your apps there to just quickly test everything is working.

In order to make your local web server public (accessible from any device), you'll need to make it accessible outside of your LAN, see:
https://superuser.com/questions/548300/how-can-make-a-web-server-publicly-accessible

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

I'm not quite there yet though. I've edited my question with some extra info that might help.

And more questions:
- "Since you are still a beginner, I'd advise you skip doing virtual hosts and just use the root www directory " - I can't actually find this directory in etc/apache2. And when you say I should skip doing virtual hosts, does that mean I shouldn't include the <VirtualHost *:80> tag?
- Should I be pointing my browser at localhost (as I would when I run rails s in development of an app), or to my IP address?

Comment: Ok, not sure if you tried- but you ran 'rails s' after rails installation right?  Because you don't really need apache, rails comes with its own webrick server that you can use. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-server

Comment: Yes, I'm very familiar with 'rails s'. I'm really just looking for a way to make my app available from other computers - temporarily of course - without having to deploy it to Heroku.
I was under the impression however, that Webrick and Apache were fundamentally different things - aren't they?
I've also just found out about 'ngrok' - I've installed it, I'm running it, but I still can't access my app (which is running on localhost:3000) through the URL it supplies, http://c297a.ngrok.com/.
Thanks for all your help - I'm looking forward to finally understanding how all this works!

Comment: Indeed Webrick and Apache are very different.  What do you mean you can't access your app?  When you run webrick and go to localhost, what shows?  Once you run webrick, you can easily then run ngrok on another terminal and it should work.  Here's how: http://www.computersnyou.com/3028/2014/03/share-localhost-world-using-ngrok-quick-tip/

Comment: Woohoo! Turns out there's no need for Apache with something so simple: I can just use ngrok to make my localhost available from anywhere, and Bob's your uncle. For other clueless rails students: install ngrok (super easy), run ./ngrok 3000 (or whatever port your app is running on), and then use the URL provided by NGROK to access it.
Thank you olive_tree for your help and patience! I've still got lots to learn and understand, but my goal for today is accomplished :-)

Comment: Glad I can help, please mark as answered (green check mark) and upvote.